# Can i accessing a property object that have Circular Reference from being Relationship method on my Nested Object Schema in Realm React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

**Hello Everyone**

My React Native App use Realm for a database, but I found a little problem where I can't access a property that has been relationship with another Schema with [Two-Many Relationship](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#to-many-relationships)
method, it's resulting a `undefined` but in the `console.log()` it's say an `[[Circular]]`

**Here result from the `console.log()` when using `REALM.objects('CUSTOMERS')[0]` method and also my customer data structure**

```
{
    "id": 1600502223352,
    "name": "Empink",
    "photo": "unknown",
    "dateCreated": 2020-09-19T07:58:29.086Z,
    "dateUpdated": 2020-09-19T07:58:29.086Z,
    "device": [[Circular]], // Relationship with "CUSTOMER_DEVICE" Schema
    "statusData": [[Circular]], // Relationship with "CUSTOMER_DATA_STATUS" Schema
    "downPayment": 50000,
    "servicePrice": 250000,
    "notes": "Phone Pin 3778"
}
```

**I am try to access a `device` property directly like**

```
let myDataObj = REALM.objects('CUSTOMERS');

console.log(myDataObj[0].device);
```

**but it's resulting an Error**

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'myDataObj[0].device')

**This is my `realmdb.js` file and a `Customer Data Schema` looks like**

In this file, a reason I export a Realm `.open()` method is that i want to call Realm from another file too

```
import Realm from 'realm';

const CUSTOMER_DEVICE = {
  name: 'CUSTOMER_DEVICE',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'int',
    brand: 'string',
    name: 'string',
    color: 'string',
    damage: 'string'
  }
};

const CUSTOMER_DATA_STATUS = {
  name: 'CUSTOMER_DATA_STATUS',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'int',
    type: 'string',
    date: 'date'
  }
};

const CUSTOMERS = {
  name: 'CUSTOMERS',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'int',
    dateCreated: 'date',
    dateUpdated: 'date',
    name: 'string',
    photo: 'string',
    device: 'CUSTOMER_DEVICE[]',
    statusData: 'CUSTOMER_DATA_STATUS[]',
    downPayment: 'float',
    servicePrice: 'float',
    notes: 'string'
  }
};

export default Realm.open({
  path: 'myApp.realm',
  schema: [CUSTOMER_DEVICE, CUSTOMER_DATA_STATUS, CUSTOMERS]
});
```

There's no error when I am try to add another data with Realm `.write()` and `.create()` method, it's just normally fine

And bay the way it's a just a little problem, I can use some method like  **`call all schema > and Object.assign() all the data into one new variable`** but I don't really like it about this method because a performance reason

And if the Realm can't do that, there's no idea and i will use that method, **OR** maybe you guys know how to access a property that has been relationship with another Schema in Realm Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes, you can!

Since I searching and try understanding about my problem, try this, and try that, I just found some issue it's called [JSON.stringify() cannot serialize cyclic structures](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3183) also [This Issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3234) solve my problem too. see all Issue in [Repo Realm Javascript](https://github.com/realm/realm-js)

#### First

Realm Javascript has some method called `JsonSerializationReplacer` that solves circular structures when serializing Realm entities, it's mean a `Circular Reference` can be converted to a plain object

**How to usage**

```
import Realm from 'realm'

// Imagine you're trying to retrieve a person data from Person Schema
const SomeJsonString =
    JSON.stringify(Realm.objects('Person'), Realm.JsonSerializationReplacer);
```

**Example result WITHOUT JsonSerializationReplacer**

```
{
    "id": 1600502223352,
    "name": "Empink",
    "photo": "unknown",
    "dateCreated": 2020-09-19T07:58:29.086Z,
    "dateUpdated": 2020-09-19T07:58:29.086Z,
    "device": [Circular],
    "statusData": [Circular],
    "downPayment": 50000,
    "servicePrice": 250000,
    "notes": "Phone Pin 3778"
}
```

**Example result WITH JsonSerializationReplacer**

```
{
    "id": 1600502223352,
    "name": "Empink",
    "photo": "unknown",
    "dateCreated": 2020-09-19T07:58:29.086Z,
    "dateUpdated": 2020-09-19T07:58:29.086Z,
    "device": {
        "name": "iPhone 5"
    },
    "statusData": {
        "type": "onprocess"
    },
    "downPayment": 50000,
    "servicePrice": 250000,
    "notes": "Phone Pin 3778"
}
```

#### Second

DO NOT USE `primaryKey` property in Child Schema just use once in Parrent Schema it will be resulting an `ERROR` if you using `JsonSerializationReplacer` Method

**Simple example Bad Schema**

```
import Realm from 'realm';

const CHILD_SCHEMA_1 = {
    name: "CHILD_1",
    primaryKey: "user_id",
    properties: {
        user_id: "string",
        user_name: "Mia"
    }
};

const CHILD_SCHEMA_2 = {
    name: "CHILD_2",
    primaryKey: "user_id",
    properties: {
        user_id: "string",
        user_hobby: "Coding Stuff"
    }
};

const PARRENT_SCHEMA = {
    name: "THE_PARRENT",
    primaryKey: "user_id",
    properties: {
        user_id: "string",
        user_details_1: "CHILD_1"
        user_details_2: "CHILD_2"
    }
};

Realm.open({
    schema: [CHILD_SCHEMA_1, CHILD_SCHEMA_2, PARRENT_SCHEMA]
}).then(function(realm) {
    // do some realm stuff
}).catch(function(RealmError){
    console.error(RealmError)
});
```

#### And that's it

I don't know why Realm didn't add `JsonSerializationReplacer`, and the other things method to the Docs but in the end, it solve my problem :)